# Assign a label to the text of a UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uidatepicker

I have a `UIDatePicker` in which I'm trying to make it scroll horizontally instead of vertically. I found [this tutorial](https://isujith.wordpress.com/2009/03/17/horizontal-uipickerview/) which shows how to do it with a **`UIPickerView`** but not a `UIDatePicker`.

The only problem I have is with the following line:

```
label.text = [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

What would I put in `label.text =`? There isn't an `array` I can `assign` to the 'label`.

Here is the full method I got from the tutorial.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 80);
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
    CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(3.14/2);
    rotate = CGAffineTransformScale(rotate, 0.25, 2.0);
    [label setTransform:rotate];
    label.text = [pickerViewArray objectAtIndex:row];
    label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:22.0];
    label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    label.numberOfLines = 2;
    label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    label.clipsToBounds = YES;
    return label ;
}
```

Comment: plz be more clear ? your question is not clear enough ? what is your problem ? and what about UIDatePicker ? what does pickerViewArray stand for ? is it UIPickerView or DatePicker ?

Comment: I'ts in the tutorial I linked to. I'll provide the full code.

Comment: make sure you have enough values in array to set in label's text. what issue you're facing? is it crashing?

Comment: The UIDatePicker doesn't have an array. So what can put in label.text = ???

Comment: @Jessica pickerViewArray have your value like John Appleseed", @"Chris Armstrong", @"Serena Auroux", in the example , so u can fill with what u want

Comment: @Omarj But I'm using a **UIDatePicker**, so I don't have that array. I have apples provided array for the dates.

Comment: @Jessica u get the date from the picker and convert it to string and put to your label . [youDatePicker date];

Comment: @Omarj Would I convert the date a a string with NSDateFormatter ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter;

formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];


yourLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[formatter stringFromDate:[birthdayPicker date]]];
```

**I think you trying to do something like** [this example](https://github.com/m1entus/MZDayPicker)

```
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE/YYYY"]; // Sun/2015
```

or

```
[self.dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EE/YY"]; // Sun/15
```

and here u can set the current date and the start/end date for your picker

```
[self.dayPicker setStartDate:[NSDate dateFromDay:31 month:5 year:2015] endDate:[NSDate dateFromDay:5 month:6 year:2016]];

[self.dayPicker setCurrentDate:[NSDate dateFromDay:31 month:5 year:2015] animated:NO];
```

[image]

Comment: That's EXACTLY what I want!! The only thing is, that it only has the current month. Do you know of something similar that has more than the current month?

Comment: @Jessica first download the sample , then in MZViewController.m u can find that you can set the format u want and the max/min date for your picker

Comment: @Jessica update my answer , and be sure that u can change the hight and width for  each cell in picker view

Comment: What are the things in the tableView? Can I remove it? I will just be needing the top part, the calendar.

Comment: @Jessica yeah u can , the table view is only for display date but u can remove it , u only need to import the MZDayPicker folder to your project and follow the How To Use in the link  ,  do u have skype add me if u need anything else "omar-johari"  ?

Comment: How can I get it to select the current date? When I do setCurrentDate:[NSDate date], it doesn't give me the right result.

Comment: @Jessica [self.dayPicker setCurrentDate:[NSDate date] animated:NO];